# Парсер данных с карты

Tags: карты, парсер, javascript, php

Привет всем!

Вот ломаю голову, как можно забрать с этой карты координаты каждого транспорта и их координатами, может что посоветуете?

Вот сама ссылка: http://transport.orgp.spb.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По определению, все иконки транспортов наносятся на карту через JavaScript. Читай доки по API OpenStreetMap: какими именно методами добавляются и перемещаются пиктограммы на их картах. Затем, ковыряй исходники: где и кем эти методы вызываются на этой странице. Когда найдешь где и кем в коде страницы добавляются и перемещаются пиктораммы, там-же можно будет увидеть откуда берутся исходные данные (например: координаты).

Ну а дальше уже можно будет определиться со стратегией сбора информации.

Answer (score 1):

Не тратьте время. Там нет координат, картинка генерится сервером и забирается по протоколу WMS. В процессе разработки отдельное API для внешних программ, там уже будут доступны координаты.

Comment: А вот, собсно и координаты в формате GTFS-realtime:
http://transport.orgp.spb.ru/Portal/transport/api/gtfs

Пример визуализации: http://t.co/nmrhy72M

Comment: > Можете рассказать по подробнее когда будет API и можно ли уже сейчас с ним работать.
API есть и работает, но доступ к нему закрыт по распоряжению товарищей комитета по транспорту. Там сейчас новый начальник (http://www.fontanka.ru/2013/08/12/094/) - можете попробовать обратиться с просьбой в комитет (http://gov.spb.ru/gov/otrasl/c_transport/obrasheniya-grazhdan/feedback/), может быть они согласятся открыть доступ.